# Iterate through data of arbitrary memory address

Tags: c, pointers

I want to loop through memory range 0x080481b8 - 0x080481c8, and print the hex representation as displayed below.

```
Hex dump of section '.note.gnu.build-id':
...
0x080481b8     7fc01d70 f4929067 e58fe5a3 9996d24d ...p...g.......M
```

What I am doing:

```
unsigned int address = 0x080481b8;
unsigned int *address_p = &address;

for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
    printf("%02hhx ", address_p[x]);
}
```

my output:

```
$ ./test
2C 77 14 52 52 04 10 01 47 00 03 02 00 02 13 01
```

wanted output:

```
$ ./test
7f c0 1d 70 f4 92 90 67 e5 8f e5 a3 99 96 d2 4d
```

> How to iterate through data of an arbitrary memory address?

Comment: `unsigned int *address_p = &address;` That takes the address of the address and is not what you want. You just want the pointer to point to the memory address. Also, it seems you want one byte at a time so use `char *` rather than `int *`. So: `unsigned char *address_p = (unsigned char *)0x080481b8 ;`

Comment: Isn't it `unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)0x080481b8;
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++) {
       printf("%02x ", (unsigned)p[i]);
    }` (Not sure if that cast in the `printf` is needed.)

Comment: How are you dumping the hex, that might not be the absolute address you are looking for if you are performing hexdump on the file.

Comment: @ikegami yes it should be an unsigned char as we are concerned with displaying consecutive bytes.

Comment: @rsonx, It's `(unsigned)` I'm not sure about. Will the `unsigned char` get promoted to `unsigned int` automatically, or is `(unsigned)` necessary?

Comment: @ikegami bytes are often unsigned 8 bit long. Also `unsigned char *p = (void*)memoryAddress` is a good way to write. When we are de-referencing the pointer, we get an unsigned char having the value same as the byte which the pointer was referencing. With the format specifier we are just printing the hexadecimal representation of this value.

Comment: @rsonx. Again, wasn't asking about that. At issue is that `%x` expects an `unsigned int`, not an `unsigned char`. How does one properly pass an `unsigned char` to it? Will the `unsigned char` get promoted automatically, or is a cast needed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205185/discussion-between-rsonx-and-ikegami).